# Refactoring Python Code when the only thing changes are methods?

Tags: python, refactoring

Need some advice on how to refactoring this kind of code, as you can see, the basic code for all, left, right is the same, all what is changing is .strip(), .lstrip(), .rstrip(), is it possible to refactor this in a "beautiful" manner?

```py
def clean_whitespaces(input, mode='all', ):
    result = None
    modes = (None, 'all', 'left', 'right')
    if mode not in modes:
        raise ValueError('clean_whitespaces: mode must be one of {}.'.format(modes))

    if mode == None:
        mode = 'all'

    if mode == 'all':
        if isinstance(input, str):
            result = input.strip()
        else:
            input = list(input)
            result = [entry.strip() for entry in input]
        return result

    elif mode == 'left':
        if isinstance(input, str):
            result = input.lstrip()
        else:
            input = list(input)
            result = [entry.lstrip() for entry in input]
        return result

    elif mode == 'right':
        if isinstance(input, str):
            result = input.rstrip()
        else:
            input = list(input)
            result = [entry.rstrip() for entry in input]
        return result
```

Comment: using dictionaries possibly, also `input` really shouldn't be used as a name for anything, it is a built-in

Comment: Agree with the use of dictionaries above. Your options for the values of the dictionary would either be the methods themselves (e.g. `entry.strip`) or the names of them (e.g. `'strip'`) which can then be looked up using `getattr`.

Comment: Use 'getattr', see my answer pls

Comment: well both answers below are "beautiful" on its own, hard to decide what kind of style (dict or lambda), is there any difference in kind of "do's and don't"

Comment: in the lambda option you still iterate 3 times, by using 'getattr' you dont need to iterate over and over again

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dict for this:

```
modes_to_func = {'all': str.strip, 'left': str.lstrip, 'right': str.rstrip}
```

This way, you can avoid iterate over the `modes`:

```
def clean_whitespaces(input, mode='all', ):
    modes = (None, 'all', 'left', 'right')
    modes_to_func = {'all': str.strip, 'left': str.lstrip, 'right': str.rstrip}
    if mode not in modes:
        raise ValueError('clean_whitespaces: mode must be one of {}.'.format(modes))

    if mode is None:
        mode = 'all'

    if isinstance(input, str):
        result = modes_to_func[mode](input)

    else:
        input = list(input)
        result = [modes_to_func[mode](entry) for entry in input]
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

So apparently you can do sth like `str.strip(string_to_strip)` (kinda makes sense because you simply pass in the instance (`self`)) which allows for this (with a few test cases at the end):

```py
def clean_whitespaces(data, mode='all'):
    modes = {None: str.strip, 'all': str.strip,
             'left': str.lstrip, 'right': str.rstrip}
    if mode not in modes:
        raise ValueError(f'clean_whitespaces: mode must be one of '
                         f'{", ".join(map(repr, modes.keys()))}.')

    if isinstance(data, str):
        result = modes[mode](data)
    else:
        result = [modes[mode](str(entry)) for entry in list(data)]
    return result


case = '                      super long spaces before                           '
correct_cases = [
    'super long spaces before',
    'super long spaces before',
    'super long spaces before                           ',
    '                      super long spaces before'

]
for m, c in zip((None, 'all', 'left', 'right'), correct_cases):
    assert clean_whitespaces(case, 'w') == c
print('passed assertion')
```

Note: for some reason PyCharm doesn't like this because of some *unexpected argument* although doing it directly doesn't raise that warning

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary and move all redundant code out of sub function and into main function.

```
def clean_whitespace(inp, mode='all'):

    def allSelected(x):
        return x.strip()

    def rightSelected(x):
        return x.rstrip()        
   
    def leftSelected(x):
        return x.lstrip()

    mdict = {'all': allSelected , 'left': leftSelected, 'right': rightSelected} 
    if mode == None:
        mode = 'all'
    try:
        if isinstance(inp, str):
            return mdict[mode](inp)
        else:
            return [mdict[mode](entry) for entry in inp]
    except KeyError:
        print('clean_whitespaces: mode must be one of {}.'.format([mdict.keys()]))
```

Comment: there is a typo in `def leftSelected(inp):
        return x.lstrip()`inp should be x right?

Comment: Updated, thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

You can move the duplicate code into a function and customize it using a lambda:

```
def strip(strip_foo, input):
    if isinstance(input, str):
        result = strip_foo(input)
    else:
        input = list(input)
        result = [strip_foo(entry) for entry in input]
    return result


def clean_whitespaces(input, mode='all', ):
    result = None
    modes = (None, 'all', 'left', 'right')
    if mode not in modes:
        raise ValueError('clean_whitespaces: mode must be one of {}.'.format(modes))

    if mode == None:
        mode = 'all'

    if mode == 'all':
        return strip(lambda v: v.strip(), input)
    elif mode == 'left':
        return strip(lambda v: v.lstrip(), input)
    elif mode == 'right':
        return strip(lambda v: v.rstrip(), input)
```

Answer (score 0):

So after reviewing all of the answers i came up with these, its more or less a merge of the 3 answers with dicts, thanks all of you for your hints (like input)

```
def clean_whitespaces(data, mode='all', ):
result = None
modes = {
    'all': str.strip,
    'left': str.lstrip,
    'right': str.rstrip
    }

if mode not in modes:
    raise ValueError('clean_whitespaces: mode must be one of {}.'.format([key for key in modes.keys()]))

if isinstance(data, str):
    result = modes[mode](data)
else:
    data = list(data)
    result = [modes[mode](entry) for entry in data]
    return result
```

Comment: you should unindent the `return`, otherwise it will `return result` only if `data` is not a string, and `result = None` is not necessary, you will always get something as a result, alternatively you can do sth like `return result or None` if you want to explicitly return `None` in case for example `result` is an empty list

Comment: yeah right, thanks, i think this was a copy and paste thing ^^